# Compile and use boost 1.51.0 on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: c++, macos, boost, c++11, libc++

So I've spent the last 20 hours trying to get boost working under OS X 10.8, and I have finally gotten it to compile without errors, but when I try to compile a test case that uses Boost.test, I'm back again in a world of hurt.
I should mention, the reason I compile boost myself instead of using the binary available, is because I want to use c++11 and libc++.

When I compiled boost, I called b2 like this:

```
./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" link=static
```

and it compiles all file. Then I have this piece of code

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Addition
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

int addition(int i, int j)
{
    return i + j;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(universeInOrder)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(addition(2, 2) == 4);
}
```

which I
try to compile with

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -Wall -v -I/Users/cb/Downloads/boost_1_51_0 tests/arithmetic.cpp -o tests/arithmetic /Users/cb/Downloads/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a`
```

And it fails miserably, giving me this error:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o tests/arithmetic /var/folders/pg/4wcxn1j12c3188vqrv0x4w9r0000gn/T/arithmetic-UFmO1B.o     /Users/cb/Downloads/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a -lc++ -lSystem     /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(bool (*)(), int, char**)", referenced from:
      _main in arithmetic-UFmO1B.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

At first, I figured it was because boost was not compiled for 64bit so I tried telling b2 to do that specifically, but it made no difference, and I also think that it compiles for 64bit by default on OS X.

Any ideas as to why it is failing and how I get it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like bad compilation of the test. You requested

> ```
> #define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
> ```

but than you are linking the static version of boost.test

> ```
> /Users/cb/Downloads/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a
> ```

and IIRC there is a difference between the static and dynamic versions of this library. So either link the dynamic version of the library (the one with `.so` extension), or remove that define.

Comment: According to boost documentation, the BOOST_[library]_DYN_LINK symbol applies only to Windows and does not support the TEST library. The documentation also implies that boost.test cannot dynamically link. However it does work on Linux shared-only builds, and does not appear to work on OSX dynamic-only builds.

Comment: @evoskuil, BOOST_[library]_DYN_LINK is (for all the *other* components) only relevant on Windows, because only Windows require explicit export/import declarations. However, Boost.Test is special, because the static version defines `main` and the dynamic one does not. So there the symbol is relevant on all platforms.

Comment: That might be a good thing to include in the documentation, especially considering: [BOOST_WHATEVER_DYN_LINK](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) ... "Note that there may be some libraries that can only be statically linked (Boost.Test for example)..."

Comment: @evoskuil, hm, seems like a bug in the documentation, because http://www.boost.org/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html clearly has both static and dynamic usage options (and a header-only option).

Comment: @evoskuil, that said, the linking has clearly changed, because now all the variants seem to work the same way regarding injection of the `main` function. The macro still has to match, but the error is going to be different now, and be only on Windows.